# T4MVC run custom tool not generate actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I trying all possibilities: uninstall T4MVC, install another version, changing prefix, delete last line from .tt file http://hadsy.net/2011/05/17/CompilingTransformationInvalidTokenThisInClassStructOrInterfaceMemberDeclaration.aspx , also I have BaseController abstract, update Visual Studio. Generate only this (no actions for all controllers, also not generate anything for the BaseController):

public class AccountController{

```
    static readonly ViewsClass s_views = new ViewsClass();
    [GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public ViewsClass Views { get { return s_views; } }
    [GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public class ViewsClass
    {
        static readonly _ViewNamesClass s_ViewNames = new _ViewNamesClass();
        public _ViewNamesClass ViewNames { get { return s_ViewNames; } }
        public class _ViewNamesClass
        {
            public readonly string Login = "Login";
        }
        public readonly string Login = "~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Initially T4MVC works, after I changed a action and rerun tool crashed. I create another project solution to test T4MVC and works. Any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: please be more specific? which action broke it?

Comment: When Run Custom Toll all of them and for BaseController not create generated.cs file. BaseController is abstract. For all controllers generate as above. If I make revert for generated.cs files, csproj, T4MVC.cs file, and restore BaseController.generated.cs file, I can build solution but when I run again Custom Tool T4MVC same problem. @JotaBe